# EV SSL certificate issue with Firefox and IE8

Tags: firefox, ssl

I installed an EV SSL certificate issued by GeoTrust, but recently I have problems with Firefox (latest version), it says "this site does not supply identity information".
Initially I thought it was a caching problem, so I cleared cache, but this problem won't go away. Any piece of advice is highly appreciated. Thank you! Here is the link: https://www.zenmony.com/system/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing out of ordinary I can spot from your SSL setup is missing OU. Maybe try adding an OU to your certificate:

[image]

This normally involves re-creating a new private key and CSR (certificate signing request), and submitting it to GeoTrust

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So did you see the green URL in Firefox?

Comment: Thanks. It appears the problem was caused by the favicon file, which was not https.